# React native with Yarn or NPM is not finding @expo/bunyan. What I have to do?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, npm, yarnpkg

I tried to create an application with React Native, when I use the command create-react-native-app the library @expo/bunyan is not found.
I tried to clean the npm cache, changing the npm registry, but I still have the error.
That is the log.

```
Arguments:
  /usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/Cellar/yarn/1.5.1_1/libexec/bin/yarn.js add --dev --exact --ignore-optio$

PATH:
  /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/go/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versi$

Yarn version:
  1.5.1

Node version:
  8.10.0

Platform:
  darwin x64

npm manifest:
  {
    "name": "Tes",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "private": true
  }

yarn manifest:
  No manifest

Lockfile:
  No lockfile

Trace:
  Error: Couldn't find package "@expo/bunyan@1.8.10" required by "react-native-scripts" on the "npm" regi$
      at new MessageError (/usr/local/Cellar/yarn/1.5.1_1/libexec/lib/cli.js:186:110)
      at PackageRequest.<anonymous> (/usr/local/Cellar/yarn/1.5.1_1/libexec/lib/cli.js:36274:17)
      at Generator.throw (<anonymous>)
      at step (/usr/local/Cellar/yarn/1.5.1_1/libexec/lib/cli.js:98:30)
      at /usr/local/Cellar/yarn/1.5.1_1/libexec/lib/cli.js:111:13
      at <anonymous>
      at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `create-react-native-app` does not support `npm5` currently because `npm5` is buggy. you can use `npm4` or latest `npm` stable version available.

I have tried to install `create-react-native-app` library on my system having the following configuration:

node -v

v9.4.0

npm -v

5.6.0

Before installation once remove the `node_modules` and clear the `npm-cache`.

Set npm registry using `npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/` command.

Then try to install using `npm i react-native-scripts --save --use-npm --verbose` command.

If you want to install the same library using yarn then you can use `yarn global add create-react-native-app` command for the same.

Hope this will help you!

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried your solution. But I have the same error "Couldn't find package \"@expo/bunyan@1.8.10\" required by \"react-native-scripts\" on the \"npm\" registry.".

Comment: could you provide the output of `npm config get registry` command?

Comment: check once the result of `curl http://registry.npmjs.org/` command. for sure that the network is not blocking your request call.

Comment: Thanks friend I solve it reinstalling npm and changing the registry